# Documents version history no content for SharePoint online (Office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, version-history

When I right click an item in Documents and select Version History, there come up several major versions of the document and if I select one of them and click View, a dialog box [like this](https://postimg.org/image/jlof3ae2x/) shows up.

There doesn't seem to be anything useful other than the title, the buttons for deleting or restoring the version.

How do I view the content of the particular version? Do I have to restore it to view it?

When I check the Library Settings, major versions are enabled for version history of the Documents. But how can I view, or even better, compare the content of a specific version? All I can see there's just a title of the document, NO content. That's weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How do I view the content of the particular version ?**

To view version history for your list or library for a specific item.

- Click on `...` then `...` then version History as shown below.

[image]

- or select your doc and from the above ribbon select Version history as shown below.

[image]

- the following version history dialog will appear to you to see all previous version

[image]

- click on your required version to view only without restore it, or if you need to can restore it or delete it as you like.

**Do I have to restore it to view it ?**

No, only click on the version that you need to view ,you also have three option view / restore / delete.

[image]

**Can compare the content of a specific version?**

No, you can compare modified by and modified date and size but content compare are achieved manually.

but also there's a workaround to compare office doc from word itself as the following

[image]

For more details about content compare with word check [this](https://alberthoitingh.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/compare-documents-using-sharepoint-and-office/)

**[Update]**

Please try using Internet Explorer and also inPrivate mode (CTRL + SHIFT + P) to

- open the file and see if the issue persists.
- The difference between the Right-click > Save link as and the Left-click is - only that a left click will directly open the associated Office application. Office should detect and automatically opens the file as long as the file type is associated with the application. The link never opens in Office Online.

Check the [ref](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other/documents-version-history-no-content-for/2370a162-5d62-4deb-96e4-fcc6d6b32a15?auth=1)

Comment: The page layout and appearance of my Documents library seem a bit different from yours but otherwise all similar. However, when I click View of a particular major version, the dialog comes up WITHOUT any content at all. Just a name and an empty title and a few buttons e.g. delete, restore, etc. How can I view the content of a particular version? Can you post a screenshot of after you click View of a particular version?

Comment: I tried to open each version for each doc that opened successfully with diff data  , should you share what you face as screenshot ?

Comment: I asked the same question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/documents-version-history-no-content-for/2370a162-5d62-4deb-96e4-fcc6d6b32a15) and it seems it's because left click of the date and time link doesn't work. I'm using Chrome so it's probably because the file type isn't registered with any of my desktop Office programs. Maybe you can integrate the replies from the thread here and I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: the menu from the last screenshot is available only for Word? I don't see it in Excel